# M 1.9.0.1 load image url crash

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I try to load url image to be display in slider.

I use this function :

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')
            ->init($product, 'small_image', $file)
            ->resize($w, $h);
```

It works partially, on some products, no problem but for some others the website crash.
I mean after this line no more html code are generated. There is no error on nginx, php, exception.log or system.log.

So I try to do :

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')
            ->init($product, 'WTFiswrong', $file)
            ->resize($w, $h);
```

Here I have errors everywhere (It's normal because it's true) : "Fichier image introuvable." (translate : image not found)

So what's happen in the first case ?

UPDATE :

```
<?php

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::app();

$id = 397;

$x = 200;

$y = 100;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize($x, $y);

exit (0);

?>
```

This display nothing, return 500 error code with no error in error log.

UPDATE 2 :

It seems to be a memory issue, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your default images set up first. Log in to the admin area and go to **System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders**

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize($x, $y);
```

`$file` is not needed.

[EDIT]

```
Mage::app();

$id = [your product id as in entity_id];

$x = 200;

$y = 100;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

echo =  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize($x, $y);

exit (0);
```

Comment: Hi Wolfie, Unfortunately it's not working, I have the same issue.

Comment: What happens if you just put together a script in your web root, e.g. test.php with (see edited answer) and then point your browser at http://www.yoursite.com/test.php - do you get to see a URL to a cached image?

Comment: I modify some part of your code, It displays nothing, return 500 error code but without errors.